# Change php code with function

Tags: php

I have a problem with a piece of code. This code works fine. No problem.

```
include ("CCheckMail.php"); 
$checkmail = new CCheckMail ();
$emails = array ("korkula@iservicesmail.com"); 
foreach ($emails as $email) 
{ 
    if ($checkmail->execute ($email)) { return 1; } else { return 0; } 
}// end foreach
```

And now, I want to change to instead use array, I want to send the email to check by var, like this:

```
include ("CCheckMail.php");
funtion_name($email){
    $checkmail = new CCheckMail ();
    if ($checkmail->execute ($email)) { return 1; } else { return 0; } 
}


} //end function
```

The new code doesnt work I dont understand why.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: yes I think `CCheckMail` is not defined will be the message..

Comment: Your code has an extra `}` but I'm guessing this is actually just a typo? How are you calling the function? (show that code also)

Comment: and shouldn't `funtion_name(` really be `function funtion_name(`

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the object once and reusing it by passing it into the function as well as the email address you're checking.

```
//Call the checkMail class
include("CCheckMail.php");

//Define the object to work with
$checkmail = new CCheckMail();

//Function to send the emails and return response
function checkEmailFunc($email, $emailObject){    
    if ($emailObject->execute ($email)) { return 1; } else { return 0; } 
}

//Test it out
$emails = array("korkula@iservicesmail.com", "test@example.com");
foreach ($emails as $email) { 
    if (checkEmailFunc($email, $checkmail)) {
        echo "Success! Checked " . $email . "<br/>";
    } else {
        echo "Failed to check " . $email . "<br/>";
    }
}
```